# How do I create a Minecraft fabric mod that spoofs a resource pack

Tags: networking, textures, minecraft, packet, minecraft-fabric

I am attempting to create a Minecraft fabric mod (or jarmod) that, when sent a server resource pack, sends back a packet acknowledging that it has loaded the resource pack, while it actually has not. This is intended to be used to bypass the way some servers require the use of a custom texture pack, which has to be loaded every single time. A similar system is used in [Minecraft Console Client](https://github.com/MCCTeam/Minecraft-Console-Client/issues/91) ([code](https://github.com/MCCTeam/Minecraft-Console-Client/commit/344749ead2f070ba0c4b761a2e614d4030dcf9bd)), which doesn't even load textures. Is there a way to do this? I can't understand the [Fabric Networking Tutorial](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:networking), none of the code or advice seems relevant to what I am trying to do. Also, I don't use java. Is there anyone more knowledgeable on the subject who can help?